# Slowing web application with WCF on timely request

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am new for the WCF, i have web application which uses WCF Service as a data access layer. I am using wcf service library and hosterd it on IIS7. It works fine for few initial service calls but hangs an application for further request. When i reset IIS , then again it is working fine for some time. 
Below is the service configuration in web.config of web app

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IRoaster" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="199999488" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
               <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
               <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://asdf.com/RoasterService/RoasterService.Roaster.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IRoaster"
    contract="RoasterService.IRoaster" name="WSHttpBinding_IRoaster">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Is there if i comment all the wcf call then for dummy values application works fine. please suggest the appropriate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not disposing the WCF client instance at the end of the request.  Look at [this post for the gotcha's in working with WCF clients.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74129/The-Proper-Use-and-Disposal-of-WCF-Channels-or-Com)